# OpenCV C++ "CvSURFParams was not declared in this scope" error

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to implement SURF Algorithm in OpenCV C++. My includies:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
```

When I run this code line

```
CvSURFParams params = CvSURFParams(500, 1);
```

I get "CvSURFParams was not declared in this scope" error.

Please help me

Comment: The function name is  cvSURFParams, not  CvSURFParams.

Comment: I changed it but error: "cvSURFParams’ was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using the C api, use instead `cv::SURF`

Or, as suggested in the comment, the correct syntax is `CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);`

Comment: I used "using namespace cv;" below includies. I think your answer is about this.

Comment: It is not a namespace problem, you should avoid using C API and use `cv::SURF` to extract SURF descriptor. However, if you need to use C API for some legacy code you need to use the non-capital "c" when you call `cvSURFParams(500,1)`

Comment: Instead of using `cvSURFParams(500,1)` use directly `cv::SURF surf_extractor(500)`

Comment: @MESV You can find an example about how ot implement it in opencv_source_code/samples/cpp/generic_descriptor_match.cpp if you have downloaded the source package of OpenCv. Unrelated: if this answer was helpful or solved your problem please vote it or accept it as a solution for your problem

Comment: First, thanks for this advice. I opened generic_descriptor_match.cpp and i will analyze this project. Second, I will try your answer and if I solve my problem I will accept your solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the c-api wrappers for this were removed. you will have to use c++, cv::SURF, etc.